# Does $A\implies B, A \Vdash B$ hold?

Tags: logic

I am tutoring a student in mathematical logic, and I am a bit confused on how this question is intended to be answered. Here is some context on the meaning of the $\Vdash$ symbol.

Let $\Gamma$ denote a collection of Boolean formulas and $\varphi$ any statement.

We say that $\Gamma \Vdash \varphi$ if $\varphi$ is true whenever every statement in $\Gamma$ is true.

For example, if $\Gamma=\{\neg B,A \wedge B\}$ then $\Gamma \Vdash A$ since $A$ is necessarily true whenever both $\neg B$ and $A\wedge B$ are true.

The textbook states that a particular statement *holds* if it is always true.

I'm a bit confused on how I should decide whether $A\implies B, A \Vdash B$ holds.

My first instinct is construct a truth table containing statements $A$ and $B$ and to omit the row in which $A$ is true and $B$ is false, but I'm not confident with this approach.

Thoughts?

Comment: As in the definition and example you outlined, you show that if $A\to B$ and $A$ are both true, then $B$ is true. Truth tables seems like a fine approach (and if I'm following your thoughts correctly, you should omit that row, as well as both rows where $A$ is false... leaving behind one row where $B$ is true). (Minor typographical suggestions: use \models, not \Vdash, and use \to, not \implies.)

Comment: I suspect that the reason why you are asking this, is that your class/textbook may have told you the formal semantics of disjunction ($\lor$) but did not quite supply the formal semantics of conditional ($\Rightarrow$) in the same way.  Often this happens when you take the expression $A\Rightarrow B$ to be shorthand for the expression $\neg A\lor B$ and then you just apply the formal semantics of disjunction and negation.

Comment: But it may help clarify how you (or your textbook, or your professor) would demonstrate that $\{\neg B,A\land B\}\Vdash A$ holds.  Do you (they) make a truth-table?  If so, you can make a truth-table for $\{A\Rightarrow B,A \}\Vdash B$.  If you instead let $v$ be some truth-assignment which satisfies $\Gamma$ and then show that $v$ satisfies $A$, then you would go through the same process for the conditional as well.

Comment: @Addem I am not taking the class. I am a tutor of a student who is taking the class. The problem doesn't have brackets around $A\implies B,A$ which is why I'm a bit confused. Also, I believe the class formally defined and discussed truth values of implications.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, why would you omit the rows in which $A$ is false? As far as I can tell, $A\Vdash B$ if $B$ is true whenever $A$ is true. This need not imply that $A$ must always be true, which is why I think the rows where $A$ is false should be included.

Comment: @MatthewH. I assumed you were omitting the row where $A$ is true and $B$ is false since that’s the row where the assumption  $A\to B$ is false. It would stand to reason that you should also delete the rows where the other assumption, $A$, is false.  And, indeed, the remaining row where $A$ and $B$ are both true is the only one satisfying both assumptions, and $B$ is true there.

Comment: @MatthewH. also, it’s very common to omit the brackets in this situation. The question means the same thing as $\Gamma\models B$ where $\Gamma =\{A, A\to B\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show for every truth value we assign to $A,B$ we have that if both $A\to B$ and $A$ hold then $B$ holds, this is what we mean when we say $A\to B, A \models  B$. One way to show this would be to construct the truth table of $(A\to B)\land A$ and show that whenever it is true so is $B$.